# is having more copies of gene better then having it less? if it's why is it ?

Tags: dna

I was learning about elephants rarely getting cancer and learn that elephants have 40 copies of genes while human only has 2 copies of genes each from parents.

so I wonder if it's better to have more copies of the gene then having 2

Comment: I think you're reading that information wrong. They are referring to a single gene, not genes in general.

Comment: [Here is one news article about the research.](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2015/10/how-elephants-crush-cancer) They are talking about p53 tumour suppressor. Rather interesting.

Comment: I also posted the equivalent article from Nature with Remi's answer @canadianer

Comment: It depends on the gene. Multiple copies of one gene in humans can result in Huntington's Disease, while multiple copies of TP53 in elephants is beneficial. Mostly, though, it's either benign or not a good thing. NB: Not a *lot* known about Copy Number Variations, but one article states: "Some CNVs have no apparent influence on phenotype, while as many as 40 others have been definitively linked with disease."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was learning about elephants rarely getting cancer and learn that elephants have 40 copies of genes while human only has 2 copies of genes each from parents.

Where did you read that? Please always include your sources.

What you're saying is unclear but I suppose you are referring to [ploidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ploidy) variation among species and not to [CNV (Copy Number Variation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-number_variation) for specific genes. It is also possible that you mistake alleles for genes but it is impossible to tell where your misunderstanding is without reading from your source. I will assume you talked about ploidy variation.

Elephants are diploids, just like humans. So, the claim appears flat wrong.

> so I wonder if it's better to have more copies of the gene then having 2

There is no general rule. Because having a single working copy is often enough, high ploidy can be a pretty good defense against loss of function mutations but that's only valid for some time just after a recent polyplodization event as the relaxation of selection pressures against such mutations will lead these deleterious mutations to higher frequencies (at mutation - drift - selection equilibrium).

Note that doubling or halving the number of gene copies often yield to issues in dosage of mRNA and protein expressed. Related to that you might to read about [dosage compensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosage_compensation)

Comment: OP is almost certainly referring to https://www.nature.com/news/how-elephants-avoid-cancer-1.18534

Comment: (not sure where the downvote came from by the way, was not from me or related to my comment, I was just providing additional information)

Comment: Down vote solved :) I think it is good answer, and who down voted it is fool actually.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to CNV.